# Iphone 8.3 Other Storage 89gb

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, apple-watch

Upgrade to 8.3 at the time of backup I had 1.2gb of used Other Data.
Hooked up the watch, used it over the weekend and now up to 89gb of Other Data.

Turned off the Watch, and restarted the phone but I can not find anyway to remove the Used space. Deleted my main Email account but that did not free up any space.

Looked in Setting - Have 29gb of Video and other apps are around 500mb.
Not enough small apps to make up 89gb.

The Apple rep requested I restore from my Upgrade backup.
Has anyone see this happen?

Comment: Likely some kind of cache that spiraled out of control, or an error log maybe? May also be related to the watch somehow.

Comment: Thinking it is related to the watch, I set deleted and had 1.7 free.
I put the watch on the charge station, and with in 25mins I had warnings about storage being full. (While I was deleting images, it needed storage to do the restore.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Plug your device into your computer. Download the app iFunbox. Go to the root file system, then open the directory "Application Archives" then delete all of the ipa files.

Another alternative (without ads) is iMazing it does an amazing job with my files. (It's a paid app)

Comment: The error fixed then I removed the Watch and repaired it.
Was a very strange error, but is fixed now.